# Video preview of headless pi4/v2 camera board with VNC viewer

Tags: pi-4, vnc, headless

I have a raspberry pi4 connected to the SmartPi Touch2 screen and the Pi v2 camera board. I remotely access the pi from my laptop with the VNC viewer - having already enabled the experimental direct capture mode on the pi's VNC server. When I run a simple python script

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
spycam=PiCamera()
spycam.start_preview()
sleep(30)
spycam.stop_preview()
```

i can see the vid preview both on the Touch2 screen and my laptop's screen. However, when I disconnect the pi from the Touch2 (by removing the flat ribbon cable), I can still access the pi via VNC viewer, but I don't get any vid preview on my laptop screen. Since I want to use the pi headless w/ the camera board to remotely monitor an engraving lathe, is there any way around this hurdle?

Comment: Using VNC to access a headless system seems to me like a rather strange way. Have you checked alternatives like [motion](https://packages.debian.org/buster/video/motion)?

Comment: Thanx Robert. Read up a bit about motion and it seems the way to go. Will give it a shot tomorrow,